# How to convert this Lambda to an Expression

Tags: c#, linq, expression, predicate

How to convert a Func with a diferent signature to an Expression with a different signature:

how to convert when there is a custom logic in the conversion and the syntax is not quite the same.

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>) Convert(Func<T, List<TJ>, bool> expr2)
{
    // the returning bool would be the execution result of expr2(t, list) where t is the T and list is of type List<TJ>

    // the returning T would be the same T

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                  (???);
}
```

I'm trying to write the OrForEeachBatch method as shown below which will use the Or method:

```
internal static Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrForEachBatch<T, TJ>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, List<List<TJ>> batches, Func<T, List<TJ>, bool> expr2)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < batches.Count; index++)
    {
        List<TJ> eventIdBatch = batches[index];

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> converted = Convert(expr2);

        expr1 = expr1.Or(converted);
    }

    return expr1;
}
```

The problem is the Or() method requires an expression not the execution of expr2

Ultimately I could ideally be using it like this:

```
 var batches = new List<List<int>>();
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder
                    .False<Event>()
                    .Or(e => e.ModifiedDate >= modifiedSince.Value)
                    .OrForEachBatch(batches, (e, batch) => batch.Contains(e.Id));
```

Any bright developer who can solve this?

If there were with the same syntax I could be using the below method for example:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> FuncToExpression<T>(Func<T, bool> f)  
{  
    return x => f(x);  
}
```

Comment: You can't "convert" a `Func<T>` to an `Expression<Func<T>>` at runtime.  That hard work is done for you by the compiler.  (You can certainly manufacture the `Expression<Func<T>>`, but you'd have to compose all the logic yourself.)

Comment: No, you certainly can and showed how. The quesion was on how to convert when there is a custom logic in the conversion and the syntax is not quite the same. thanks

Comment: I'm not following you.  Literally the very last sentence of yours is you asking how to do it.  I am saying that "below method" is not possible to write.  Did you think I was referring to something else?  I suspect you are unaware that the "conversion" of a `Func<>` to an `Expression<Func<>>` happens at *compile time*.